# Read configuration from JSON using .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-standard, appsettings, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library and want to read config settings  from .json file instead of .config.

Currently I read .config file as :

```
config = (CustomConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SectionName);
```

where CustomConfigSection is :

```
public class CustomConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("url")]
    public CustomConfigElement Url
    {
        get => (CustomConfigElement)this["url"];
        set => this["url"] = value;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Id")]
    public CustomConfigElement Id
    {
        get => (CustomConfigElement)this["Id"];
        set => this["Id"] = value;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomConfigElement: ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("value", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Value
    {
        get => (string)this["value"];
        set => this["value"] = value;
    }
}
```

I was trying to do like :

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().
SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.Build();

_config = (CustomConfigSection) configBuilder.GetSection(SectionName);
 // Exception due to casting to inappropriate class
```

But I am getting exception.

So I think, I need to implement not ConfigurationSection class but IConfigurationSection for CustomConfigSection class.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx to [Zysce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3937941/zysce) for comment. So that's how I did and it works good.

Here I change CustomConfigSection class like :

```
public class CustomConfigSection
{
  public CustomConfigElement Url {get; set;}
  public CustomConfigElement Id {get; set;}
}
```

And read Json config as :

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

_config = configBuilder.GetSection(SectionName).Get<CustomConfigSection>();
```